# Согласование числа и рода прилагательных: "фиксированного и плавающего валютн(ых/ого) курс(ов/а)"

Tags: синтаксис, грамматика, согласование

Как правильно: "Расчет, произведённый на основе фиксированного и плавающего валютн(ых/ого) курс(ов/а)"?

Answer (score 1):

Правильно: валютного курса. Курс один, а не несколько.

Comment: Как же не несколько?  Один - фиксированный, другой - плавающий...

Comment: Сравните: "прямого и непрямого методов" vs "прямого и непрямого метода".  Первый даёт более тысячи результатов в Гугле, второй - меньше ста.

Comment: если подчеркивается наличие нескольких предметов,тогда определение ставится в мн.ч.  Ср.:биологический и химический методы; В сочетаниях же терминологического характера употребляется ед.ч.

Comment: Доказательство?  Цитата?  Только не сюда, пожалуйста, а в Ваш ответ.

Comment: Виктор, я понял насчет доказательства.

Answer (score 1):

Из [справочника Розенталя](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/65.htm):

> 4) если перечисляемые разновидности предметов или явлений внутренне связаны, например, в сочетаниях терминологического характера: ср.: в правой и левой руке (половине, стороне и т.п.); оперное и балетное искусство; промышленный и аграрный переворот; учащиеся среднего и старшего школьного возраста; программы для восьмилетней и средней школы (как системы образования); в старославянском и древнерусском книжном языке; глаголы совершенного и несовершенного вида (действительного и страдательного залога, настоящего и прошедшего времени, изъявительного и сослагательного наклонения, первого и второго спряжения и т.п.); существительные мужского, женского и среднего рода (первого и второго склонения, единственного и множественного числа); местоимения первого и второго лица; вирусный и простой грипп; головной и спинной мозг; война Алой и Белой розы.

Мне кажется, что Ваш случай соответствует этому пункту с тем отличием, что в этих примерах существительным нигде не предшествует определение. Однако мне кажется, что это принципиальной роли не играет и должно быть единственное число: "расчёт, произведённый на основе фиксированного и плавающего валютн**ого** курс**а**".

Comment: Вы правы, Артем.

Comment: Я не согласен.  См. мои коментарии к ответу Сержа.

Comment: Это не я так считаю. Я просто пошукал в интернете, нашёл это и сделал такой вывод. :)

Comment: Я понял, что это из справочника Розенталя, поэтому не стал в своем ссылаться на справочник.